# Trimming of SQL Database values from my c# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Am trying to achieve trimming my comboBox whch is getting data from my SQL Server. Am aware that the Trim function should be used. I have applied it in various ways but seem to still be faced with white spaces from my database. How do I go about including the Trim function effectively?

```
void fill()//fill combobox with values
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=cmcentraldb;Initial Catalog=CMLTD;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con2.Open();
        string query = "SELECT DISTINCT ITEMDESC  FROM dbo.IV00101"; 
        //select Convert(nvarchar(50),Item_Description)+ ':' +Convert(nvarchar(50),Item#) as Combined from Carimed
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

        SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr2.Read())
        {
            string cari_des = dr2.GetString(dr2.GetOrdinal("ITEMDESC"));
            suggestComboBox1.Items.Add(cari_des);
            suggestComboBox1.Text.Trim();
        }
        //con2.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the datatype in your database table. If its a fixed char then it will always allocate the same amount of space regardless of the size.

Comment: `suggestComboBox1.Items.Add(cari_des.Trim());`

Comment: I know it is char but the thing is that I have no admin rights to the database. Am just pulling from a particular column and trying to trim it within my application @Wheels73

Comment: @MotKohn thank you that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trim value before binding it to combobox. Do it like below:

```
void fill()//fill combobox with values
{
    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=cmcentraldb;Initial Catalog=CMLTD;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con2.Open();
        string query = "SELECT DISTINCT ITEMDESC  FROM dbo.IV00101"; 
        //select Convert(nvarchar(50),Item_Description)+ ':' +Convert(nvarchar(50),Item#) as Combined from Carimed
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query, con2);

        SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr2.Read())
        {
            string cari_des = dr2.GetString(dr2.GetOrdinal("ITEMDESC"));
            suggestComboBox1.Items.Add(cari_des.Trim());
        }
        //con2.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to trim the items that you Add to the combobox

```
suggestComboBox.Items.Add(cari_des.Trim());
```

you can delete the line, it does nothing:

```
suggestComboBox1.Text.Trim();     // delete this
```

Comment: Thank you this worked but someone already suggested the same answer. Wish I could upvote but my rep is too low. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> How do I go about including the Trim function effectively

One thing I notice is you have SQL query prepared in application side.
For many reasons this is neither good practice nor advisable.

You should have created stored procedures which returns the needed data.
implementing "Trim" function should be on database side (inside the db procedure) rather on the application side unless you are sure that data returned from the database is never going to be in large amount.

```
declare @name varchar(5)='a   '
select @name,RTRIM(LTRIM(@name))
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take that into account next time. Much appreciated. I'd upvote but my rep hasn't reached the required level yet

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Replace`

```
suggestComboBox1.Items.Add(cari_des.Replace(" ", ""));
```

**Note:** This will remove all the white spaces at start at end and in middle.